# Accessing route param value before APP_INITIALIZER startup service - angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

If I'm using startup service to check certain business rules (retrieved over web service)
and upon that information I grant or denied access to the app

inside **app.module** startup service is registered as follows
...

```
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  AppState,
  GlobalState
];

export function startupServiceFactory(startupService: StartupService): Function {
  return () => startupService.load();
}
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [App],
    declarations: [
        App    
    ],
    imports: [ 
        ...
    ]
    providers: [
        DataService,    
        StartupService,
        APP_PROVIDERS,
        {
            // Provider for APP_INITIALIZER
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
            deps: [StartupService],
            multi: true
        }
    ],
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appState: AppState) { }
}
```

Now I want further to extend this. I want to fetch route param value before startup service is entered,
and to pass this param value to the startup service.

So I tried following,

```
app.routing.ts
export const routes: Routes = [    
  { path: 'myapp/:name', component: AppComponent }   
];
```

inside **AppComponent** I tried to fetch this on init

```
ngOnInit() {    
    let name = this.route.snapshot.params["name"];
    storageService.save('nameValue', name);
 }
```

**startupService.ts**

```
 export class StartupService{
    private name: string;
    constructor(private storage: StorageService){
        this.name = storage.get(nameValue); 
    } 

    // using this.name further ... 
 }
```

This not working since startupService is loaded before AppComponent and therefore 
 name variable inside StartupService is always undefined.

> How can I change this to inject route param value to the startup
>   service over storage service (or any other way)?

Comment: why don't you just inject the route into the startup service?

Comment: I tried and I'm getting something like circular dependency (need to check exact exception).

Comment: oh yea that's right, the app initializer goes before the router is initialized.  I was thinking of non initializer factory functions.  So the answer here is that you can't use the router or actiaved route in an app initializer.  You can access the URL through typical methods though if you absolutely have to, but I think you should revisit why you want to structure this way. Your app's initialization process shouldn't be different based on the current URL

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that I can use router only after app is initialized, which makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

in startupServiceFactory, i would use window.location directly, parse the queryparam, and save the value (all in startupServiceFactory), then downstream you can use more "pure" angular code